# VS 2013 Community - Creating code snippets

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, code-snippets

I have been following this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I'm trying to make a code snippet to speed up my coding (#procrastination)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>Class layout for PlatformGameEngine</Title>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="C++">
        <![CDATA[
          namespace PlatformGameEngine
          {
              class _
              {
              // Methods
              public:
                  _();
                  ~_();
              private:

              // Properties
              public:

              private:

              }
          }
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

**1.** Why is the following code snippet not working?

> The snippet files chosen were not valid.

**2.** How can i replace the _ part for the ability to tab through fields and fill them out?

Answer (score 2):

Found an example from the Visual Studio snippet manager:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\Snippets\1033\Visual C++
```

I can see from the class example I had some missing stuff:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>Class layout for PlatformGameEngine</Title>
      <Shortcut>gameengineclass</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>name</ID>
          <ToolTip>Class name</ToolTip>
          <Default>MyClass</Default>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="cpp">
        <![CDATA[#pragma once

        // Boiler plate includes



        // Project specific includes



        // Namespaces



        namespace PlatformGameEngine
        {
            class $name$
            {
            // Methods
            public:
                          $name$();
                          ~$name$();
            private:

            // Properties
            public:

            private:

            }
        }]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

- Removed spacing after CDATA[...
- Added Shortcut node to Header
- Added declarations with ID section to allow typing in stuff

**Note:**

- You have to keep re-importing to get the changes you make to an individual snippet... But if you Add an entire folder, you do not have to do this.
- You can use `ctrl+k` and then `h` while continuing to hold down `ctrl` to use your snippet. Just start typing your shortcut and it pops up
- to remove code snippets, you must remove the entire folder and re add the folder... #really?
- If your definition is not appearing... for example: `$classname$::$classname`, Try placing a `<Default>MyClass</Default>` in... This seems to force it to work

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jimmyt1988's answer, for me, the issue was the language tag. None of the following worked:

- `<Code Language="C++">`
- `<Code Language="Visual C++">`
- `<Code Language="VisualC++">`

It only worked when I changed it to:

- `<Code Language="cpp">`

This was for Visual Studio 2015.